# MOC3021 stopped working

Tags: opto-isolator, triac

I am trying to make a dimmer circuit using an MOC3021 and a BT136.

I used a zero crossing detector with a 4N35.

The dimming is controlled with a processor.

Initially the circuit worked fine, but randomly the fan turns on and even starts shaking due to false triggering. The fan connected is a wall fan with swing option.

I have used snubber for the TRIAC and MOC3021 as well.

Dimmer circuit as suggested in datasheet:

[image]

Comment: The MOC3061/2/3 has a zero-cross built in. Is that a problem? Just asking.

Comment: It would help if you posted a schematic diagram of the circuit.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post... do not write a comment

Comment: @periblepsis I used moc3021

Comment: @JRE sorry for incomplete information. I did.

Comment: @jsotola I have added a schematic and my curcuit is exactly similar to the schematic. Triac used is BT136. Snubber is provided for both triac and opto. The circuit works fine but sometime the fan turns on automatically and starts shaking. The fan is a wall fan. I guess the triaac falsely triggers.

Comment: you still have not asked a question ... you only described the problem ... that is not a question

Comment: @jsotola my question is what could be the possible reason for this falase triggering? And how can I stop that.

Comment: please add the question to your post ... a comment is not the place for it

Comment: Please post oscillograms of relevant nodes.